I'm having issues uninstalling SQL Server
How do you uninstall SQL Server?  I accidentally installed 2 versions of SQL server and now nothing will work.  How do I undo the installations so I can get a clean install?
Right now, I'm getting the error in the screenshot.

Unable to install SQL Server.
Exit code (decimal) 2068119551
Error description:  SQL Server browser configuration for feature 'SQL_Browser_Redist_SqlBrowser_CPU32' was cancelled by user after a previous installation failure.



Are you unable to uninstall via the Windows add/remove programs?
